# Problem 5, Section 13 of Munkres' TOPOLOGY - Interesting alternate way to solve it.

Tags: general-topology

Here's Prob. 5, Sec. 13 in the book Topology by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

Show that if $\mathscr{A}$ is a basis for a topology on X, then the topology generated by $\mathscr{A}$ equals the intersection of all topologies on X that contain $\mathscr{A}$.

Let the topology generated by $\mathscr{A}$ be $T_\mathscr{A}$, and the intersection of all topologies on X that contain $\mathscr{A}$ be given by $I_\mathscr{A}$.

I now want to show that

1. ${T}_\mathscr{A}$ $\subset$ $I_\mathscr{A}$
2. $I_\mathscr{A}$ $\subset$ $T_\mathscr{A}$

The proof for (1) is easy: Let $U \in T_\mathscr{A}$. Then $U$ is written as a union of elements of $\mathscr{A}$ each of which are also contained in $I_\mathscr{A}$. And since $I_\mathscr{A}$ is topology (proved in Problem 4(a)), their union is also in $I_\mathscr{A}$. Hence ${T}_\mathscr{A}$ $\subset$ $I_\mathscr{A}$.

The proof of (2) is where I am stuck. Let $U \in I_\mathscr{A}$. Why can't this $U$ contain a non-empty subset which has no intersections with any elements of $\mathscr{A}$? The route I want to follow is to show that it is not possible to have such a non-empty subset of $U$ that has no overlaps with any elements of $\mathscr{A}$. Can someone please help me here?

Comment: **Hint** $ T_\mathscr{A}$ is one of the topologies which contains $\mathscr{A}$. Therefore, $ T_\mathscr{A}$ is one of the elements in the intersection which defines $ I_\mathscr{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a contradiction at all, nor do you have to consider an arbitrary member if $I_{\mathcal{A}}$. Main facts: $T_{\mathcal{A}}$ is a topology (this has been shown before, I hope)  and it contains $\mathcal{A}$ (trivially, as unions of singletons are also arbitrary unions). So by **definition** $I_{\mathcal{A}} \subseteq T_{\mathcal{A}}$ as any intersection of a non-empty family is a subset of any set in that family. QED.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U \in I_\mathscr{A}$. If we can prove that this $U$ is equal to the union of some elements of $\mathscr{A}$, then we can show that this $U \in T_\mathscr{A}$. Suppose, this $U$ is not equal to the union of some elements of $\mathscr{A}$, that is, it contains a small non-empty subset, $V$, that has no intersection (or nothing in common) with any elements of $\mathscr{A}$. Lets go back and look at $I_\mathscr{A}$ $-$ it is formed from intersections of all the topologies that contain $\mathscr{A}$; and one of those topologies is $T_\mathscr{A}$. This implies that $U$ must be contained in $T_\mathscr{A}$. This implies that the $V$ that we proposed ought to be empty. That is a contradiction. Hence $U$ is equal to the union of some elements of $\mathscr{A}$ and nothing else, hence $I_\mathscr{A} \subset T_\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: No need for a contradiction etc. Just remark what @N.S and I did in our answers.